# Did Panaka know who Padme really was?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In Episode I, we see Panaka very concerned about landing on Tatooine, because the planet is controlled by the Hutts...

Later, when Qui-Gon is heading to the city, Panaka insists that he takes Padme with him. It would be very strange if he actually knew that:

> Padme was actually the Queen.. :)

But in Episode II, Padme's new bodyguard, Cap. Typho, knows about her decoy... Which led me thinking if Panaka did know it either before she revealed it... If he did, wasn't it very strange that he insisted that she went with Qui-Gon to explore an unknow planet?

Comment: Panaka insisted Padme accompany them because Padme ordered him to. As a mere "handmaiden" she had no authority but she used her authority over him to make sure she could go.

Comment: As I recall, he said "the Queen insists" or something to that effect.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe "The Queen wishes it" were his exact words.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [The New Essential Guide To Characters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Characters), **yes, he knew**.

The whole idea of using a double was his to begin with.

Per [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Quarsh_Panaka):

> Panaka was appointed head of security in Magneta's stead; one of Queen Amidala's first acts as regent. Panaka took the death of Veruna particularly hard, and he felt the late King's death was his fault. To ensure this never happened again, **he developed an elaborate security setup, which involved using the Queen's handmaidens as decoys.** The ploy saved the life of Amidala more than once.

Answer (score 12):

### First notes

As to the first part of your question, i refer you to the excellent [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/75625/33325) by @phantom42.
The other part of your question will be answered based on my knowledge of the movies and the script, as can be seen below.

### Why he insisted

Actually, Panaka didn't insist; the Queen did.

Panaka states that it is the Queen that has commanded (and wished) the handmaiden be brought along, with him only acting as the messenger of this command. I think it's fair to assume that he was given these instructions off-screen, by the Queen (Padmé), and simply acted on them.

### References

**Part of the movie script, conveying the exchange between Panaka, Qui-Gon and Padmé**

> ```
>   From the spaceship, CAPT. PANAKA and PADME run toward them.
>
>   CAPT. PANAKA    Wait!
>
>   QUI-GON stops as they catch up. PADME is dresses in rough peasant's
>   garb.
>
>   CAPT. PANAKA    Her Highness commands you to take her handmaiden with
>                   you. She wishes for her to observe the local...
>
>   QUI-GON         No more commands from Her Highness  today, Captain. This
>                   spaceport is not going to be pleasant...
>
>   CAPT. PANAKA    The Queen wishes it. She is curious about this
>                   planet.
>
>   PADME           I've been trained in defense... I can take care of myself.
>
>   CAPT. PANAKA    Don't make me go back and tell her you refuse.
>
>   QUI-GON         I don't have time to argue. But this is not a good idea.
>                   Stay close to me.
>
>   He gives PADME a stern look.
> ```

source: [script](http://sfy.ru/?script=star_wars_episode_1)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes he did.** This point is explictly address in the (until recently) canon sourcebook [Star Wars : The New Essential Guide to Characters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Characters).

[image]

That being the case, it explains the fact that he was somewhat curt with the Jedi when he asked them to take Padme into Mos Eisley. He wasn't directing his frustration at them but rather at the Queen who was stood next to him in disguise.